# Wordpress php, subscribe to forum if topic is > certain_date

Tags: php, wordpress, bbpress

I'm trying to create a php script to check if each bbpress topic is newer than certain date, so if it's true, subscribe the author of that topic to that forum (I only have 1 bbpress forum so there is no need to check the id of that forum).

This is the code at this point:

```
<?php

$args = array(  
    'post_type'        => 'topic',  
);
$post = get_posts( $args ); 
$compare_date = strtotime( "2015-07-14" );

foreach($post->ID as $topic){
    $post_date    = strtotime( $post->post_date );
    $post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $topic );
    if ( $compare_date < $post_date  ) {        
        bbp_add_user_forum_subscription($post_author_id ,1687); 
    }   
}
?>
```

where 1687 is the id of the forum I want them to subscribe.

This is not working, I added that piece of code to my functions.php file and reloaded my website but nothing changed in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '%wp__bbp_forum_subscriptions%'
```

Comment: You have a typo here: strtotime( $post->post_date ); Should be $topic. Does that help?